# Adding border on icons in openlayers

Tags: openlayers, web-mapping, mapping

I am trying to add borders to the icons in open layers and I am able to do so but when i try to increase the thickness of the border, the border is not uniform and at one side becomes larger than other sides. How do i fix this?

```
var activeColor = "red";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.css']
})
export class MapComponent implements OnInit {
  iconFeatures:Feature = [];
  ngOnInit(){



    var iconFeature = new Feature({
      geometry: new Point([0, 0]),
      color: 'green',
      scale: 0.1,
      imgSrc: "assets/non_transparent.jpg"

    });
    iconFeature.set("style",this.createStyle(iconFeature.get("imgSrc"),undefined));

    this.iconFeatures.push(iconFeature);


    var map = new Map({
      layers: [
        new TileLayer({
          source: new OSM()
        })
      ],
      target: document.getElementById("map"),
      view: new View({
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 3
      })
    });

    var vectorSource= new VectorSource({
      features:this.iconFeatures,
      wrapX: false

    });
    console.log("Entering vector layer");

    var vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
      source: vectorSource,
      style: function(feature) {
        console.log("inside style function");
        if (feature.get("color") !== activeColor) {
          var initStyle = feature.get("initStyle");
          if (!initStyle) {
            initStyle = feature.get("style");
            feature.set("initStyle", initStyle);
          }
          var image = initStyle.getImage().getImage();

          if (image.width > 0) {
            console.log("inside width > 0");

            var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); //this method returns an object that provides methods and properties for drawing on the canvas. eg: text, line, boxes, circles, and more

            var dArr = [-1,-1, 0,-1, 1,-1, -1,0, 1,0, -1,1, 0,1, 1,1], // offset array
            s = 100,  // thickness scale
            i = 0,  // iterator
            x = 6,  // final position
            y = 6;

            // fill with color


            //set new canvas dimentions adjusted for border
            canvas.width = image.width + s + s;
            canvas.height = image.height + s + s ;

            // draw images at offsets from the array scaled by s
            for (; i < dArr.length; i += 2){
              ctx.drawImage(image, x + dArr[i] * s, y + dArr[i + 1] * s);
            }


            // fill with color
            ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";
            ctx.fillStyle = activeColor;
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

            // draw original image in normal mode
            ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
            ctx.drawImage(image, x, y); //, image.width, image.height);


            //create new openlayers icon style from canvas
            var newStyle = new Style({
              image: new Icon(
                /** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
                  crossOrigin: "anonymous",
                  src: undefined,
                  img: canvas,
                  imgSize: canvas
                    ? [canvas.width, canvas.height]
                    : undefined,
                  scale: feature.get('scale')
                })
              )
            });

            feature.set("style", newStyle);
            feature.set("color", activeColor);

          }
        }
        return feature.get("style");

      }
    });
    map.addLayer(vectorLayer);

}



  public createStyle(src, img) {
    return new Style({
      image: new Icon({
        anchor: [0.5, 0.96],
        crossOrigin: "anonymous",
        src: src,
        img: img,
        imgSize: img ? [img.width, img.height] : undefined,
        scale: 1
      })
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is again one of those HTML only questions that by the book shouldn't be answered here. But rules are there to be broken (sometimes).

Border around image here is drawn by displacing original image in eight different directions and drawing this displaced images on canvas and then overlaying this by original image. Displacement amount is `s` (called thickness scale here). What's wrong in the code above that the origin coordinate for displaced image (and later overlayed original image) is constant `[6, 6]` instead of being displacement amount `[s, s]`.

So what needs to be changed in the code above is simply replacing

```
x = 6, 
y = 6;
```

by

```
x = s, 
y = s;
```

Comment: This works but for some reason only the first icon gets the border and other icons dont even appear in the map. whereas when i remove the style function then all the icons appear. Any idea why this is happening

Comment: Did they appear before applying this solution?

Comment: no they did not. but the border only applies to one icon and that too the first one.

Comment: Since in the question there was no mention of other icons not appearing, this means your questions as it was stated was answered and problem solved. If you have another question/problem, please put it as a new separate question.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/352739/can-only-add-border-to-one-icon-using-style-function

Comment: If answer solved the problem from your question, you should accept it, so it will be clear to others with the same problem that the problem was solved.

Comment: Done, can you help me with the other question ?

Comment: I'll have a look when I come home, I'm at my job now.